# How to get the default project directory in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to set up an installer that copies zipped exported Project Templates I made to the default project directory's Project Templates folder, as this seems to be the easiest way to incorporate custom templates in the New Project wizard.

For most people, the location will be `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ProjectTemplates`, but I'm pretty sure this is not guaranteed, or at least not static.

Is there a way I can retrieve this information via macros, or programmatically? If only the latter, C# and C++ are preferred for examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read them from registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0
```

These are under the keys:

"UserItemTemplatesLocation" and "UserProjectTemplatesLocation".

Depending the installer technology you use, but WiX for example, has `RegistrySearch` element which allows you to read registry values on the fly, and copy files to specific place.

It's unclear what you're exactly looking (your title wants project folder, but then you're talking about template folder), there is also "VisualStudioProjectsLocation" registry key

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you, Chris! I'll look into that WiX thing, later.

Answer (score 1):

OP, here. I'm sharing a mini C# program to help you get this information in a Console Application. Chris's answer was what I was looking for, so just use this time-saver if you aren't utilizing WiX:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace FindDefaultProjectTemplates
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0");
            Object obj = key.GetValue("UserProjectTemplatesLocation");
            Console.WriteLine(obj);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```